# How to fix "svn: Unable to parse URL " due to spaces in file name

Tags: svn

I moved a directory from one branch to other e.g

```
svn move "branchA/src/design mockups"  branchB/src/newname
```

But when I try to svn update specially on linux I get message like this:

```
svn: Unable to parse URL '/svn/my_project/!svn/bc/6070/mb_project/branches/branchB/src/design mockups/scrum-mockup.jpg
```

what are chances to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you affected by this bug, by chance?

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1284641